# Remove a given string from an input value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden field with three integer values, example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="10 23 42">
```

I want to use jQuery to remove a given value, say "10", which would leave the remaining "23 42" value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script>
    $("input").val($("input").val().replace("10 ", ""));
</script>
```

Comment: I'm certainly not diminishing this answer but it should be noted that it selects the element twice, which _may_ be a performance concern.

Comment: You should be very careful with this as I think "10 23 42 310 15" would end up "23 42 3 15". Likewise if your value was "23 42 10" nothing would get replaced. You can still use .val to extract your value but I would recomend storing them as an array and using javascript to splice the propper element out before reasigning it.

Comment: Excellent point @jdcook72. I suggest using a regexp. `/10 ?/` works as expected _assuming_ only one occurrence of '10' to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as @Shaz answer but perhaps a little cleaner. This uses a function that returns the val to use. See the API docs at http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$('input').val(function(index, val){
    return val.replace('10', '').trim();
});
```

To handle the possible trailing space after your integer:

```
val.replace(/10 ?/, '').trim()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_input" value = "10 23 42">
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $("my_input").attr("value", $("my_input").attr("value").replace("10 ", ""));
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should use "val", It is more convenient and easier to read