# How to remove a string from an input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [read this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496426/1018804) and this is the code I am using:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>

<input name="usp-custom-2" id="usp-custom-2" type="text" value="" data-required="true" placeholder="Example Input 2" class="usp-input usp-input-custom usp-form-253" required="required">
```

**JS**

```
  $(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
    var removeThisId = "<?php echo $idThisPost; ?>";
    $("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-2").val($("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-2").val().replace(removeThisId));
  });
```

The `php` sets `var removeThisId` as `248`

But when I click the `remove button` the input field value becomes:

> undefined248

While I am expecting to simply remove the value.

Also note that the `input values` could have `248,242` so two variables and a comma, clicking on remove should remove the current ID and the comma if present.

Comment: Could I know why I got downvotes?

Comment: Try once `$("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-2").val(function (_, value) {
 return value.replace(removeThisId, '')
});`

Comment: @Durga there have been dugging indeed

Comment: @Satpal nope, nothing happens

Comment: you are replacing with `undefined` thats why you are getting that. here is [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: you shouldn't mix php with js - it just doesn't work, use hidden DOM elements with data-* attributes

Comment: @Durga I have linked and stated an answer from a SO within my question

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it does work, i get the correct value in the js var

Comment: `replace` need a second argument `str.replace("replaced", "replacement");`

Comment: @sTx I tried `.replace(removeThisId,''));` but nothing happens

Comment: `$("#usp-form-253 #usp-custom-2")` just log this and check what you are getting? and check about jquery [selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). There is no element having both the id.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs ok i went your route and it works so if you put it into an answer I will accept it  `<span  class="removeId" data-thisPostId="<?php echo $idThisPost; ?>"></span> $(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
    var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId");
    $("#usp-custom-2").val($("#usp-custom-2").val().replace(removeThisId,''));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace it with `''` (no value) to get rid of that `undefined`. Also, since you are using `id` selector you can simply use that `usp-custom-2` id without using `id` usp-form-253 in your query selector. For the example I have preset the value of `input`.

```js
$(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){
    var removeThisId = "248";
    $("#usp-custom-2").val($("#usp-custom-2").val().replace(removeThisId,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='#usp-form-253'>
<button type="button" class="removeJiku btn btn-danger">Remove</button>

<input name="usp-custom-2" id="usp-custom-2" type="text" data-required="true" placeholder="Example Input 2" class="usp-input usp-input-custom usp-form-253" required="required" value='248abcd'>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: @rob.m check now. I have preset the value of input. You can simply click the button to check.

Comment: This is what eventually worked `<span  class="removeId" data-thisPostId="<?php echo $idThisPost; ?>"></span> $(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){ var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId"); $("#usp-custom-2").val($("#usp-custom-2").val().replace(removeThisId,''));`

Comment: What's the difference? you customised the code based on your situation in  `removeThisId` and I simply hard coded that for the example @rob.m

Comment: the difference is that a comment suggested not to mix php and js and i think it's more correct, yours works tho.

Comment: I just mocked the PHP part. As you have said in question that you get value correctly from that PHP.

Comment: I am glad to help you.